# Как в Firebird создать процедуру для поиска строки в таблице?

Tags: sql, firebird

мне нужна помощь с созданием процедуры для Firebird (Версия 2.5, если это важно), которая будет осуществлять поиск строки в таблице, после того как пользователь введёт в текстовое поле программы какие-нибудь данные (с взаимодействием с процедурой из своей программы я разберусь сам). В этой хранимой процедуре входящим параметром должна быть переменная с текстом для поиска, а выходящим параметром найденная строка или переменная некого типа. Буду признателен, как объяснениям, так и просто готовому коду, но сопроводите его пожалуйста хотя бы краткими комментариями, потому что я хочу действительно разобраться, а не просто скопировать. Спасибо!

Comment: Может это поможет http://www.ibase.ru/sp_call/, там примеры с выбором данных из таблицы внутри процедуры

Comment: Поиск по точному совпадению введенного текста и значения ячейки таблица, по вхождению введенного текста в ячейку таблицы, по вхождению введенного текста в любое поле таблицы или еще как?

Answer (score 0):

Простейший пример. Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (
    ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME  VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL
);
```

Поиск можно сделать такой процедурой

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE (
  INPUT_TEXT VARCHAR(127)
)
RETURNS (
  ID INTEGER,
  NAME VARCHAR(127)
)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT
      FIRST 10
      T.ID, T.NAME
    FROM TABLE_1 T
    WHERE T.NAME CONTAINING :INPUT_TEXT
    INTO
      :ID, :NAME
  DO
    SUSPEND;
END
```

Пояснения:

- `FIRST 10` - выводить не более 10 результатов. Если нужны все, просто убрать эту конструкцию.
- `A CONTAINING B` - истинно, если `A` содержит `B` как подстроку. Еще есть `A STARTING WITH B` - поиск по началу, и тривиальное `A = B`.

Comment: [Я получил ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCR66.png)

Comment: @ValentinK., текстом, пожалуйста

Comment: просто написано Error я поэтому и скинул скрин

Comment: Посмотрел скриншот. Во-первых, там написано "Token unknown - line 3, column 1 CREATE", а не просто Error. Во-вторых, уберите весь сгенерированный IBExpert'ом тест, оставьте только то, что в ответе